# How to send a packet through Bluetooth to another Bluetooth enabled device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, distance

I am working on an android application which would measure distance between two mobile device. I have been able to get rssi of nearby wifi enabled devices which I then use to roughly calculate the distance which usually does not have great accuracy. To improve the accuracy I also want to measure round trip time.

So my question is how can you send a packet from one android device to another via bluetooth or wifi signal if possible and then receive a response? Also do the devices have to be paired in each case or is knowing a mac address enough?

Answer (score 0):

A quick googling will lead you to the android dev tutorial. [There](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection) you should find the answer for your questions. However to sum it up: To find other devices via bluetooth you can use the bluetooth adapter. There you can try to discover new bluetooth devices or query a list of devices, which have been connected to the android device before.

Sending a packet works with `OutputStream.write()` reading with `InputStream.read()`

You will find at the dev site an example for this, but in short it could look like this (modified version of the example provided in the tutorial):

```
        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
 public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
     try{
            is= socket.getInputStream();
            os = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes=0; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs or the stream ends
        while (bytes != -1) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream, the read bytes will be stored in the array
                bytes = is.read(buffer); //reads 1024 bytes into the buffer
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            os.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
```

Comment: what is `mmInStream`?

Comment: @user924 should have been is so the input stream, I corrected it.